# How to optimize below code

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am programming on spring project. The Formatter(org.springframework.format.Formatter) is used to convert the entity in the model to String in order to be printed out in JSP page and also convert the string to the entity again so that controller could handle entity directly. I followed the example of pet clinic.

```
public class PetTypeFormatter implements Formatter<PetType> {

    private final ClinicService clinicService;


    @Autowired
    public PetTypeFormatter(ClinicService clinicService) {
        this.clinicService = clinicService;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(PetType petType, Locale locale) {
        System.out.println("PetTypeFormatter: print");
        return petType.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public PetType parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("PetTypeFormatter: parse");      
        Collection<PetType> findPetTypes = this.clinicService.findPetTypes();
        for (PetType type : findPetTypes) {
            if (type.getName().equals(text)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new ParseException("type not found: " + text, 0);
    }

}
```

Controller has the model attribute called "types" mapping to Collection declared as code below:

```
    @ModelAttribute("types")
    public Collection<PetType> populatePetTypes() {
        return this.clinicService.findPetTypes();
    }
```

In JSP page, create a select box, which should list all types in String by *PetTypeFormatter.print()* method. You only need to parse *types* to select box *names* field.

```
 <petclinic:selectField names="${types}" name="type" label="Type" size="5"/>
```

And in turn, use select string from select box, *PetTypeFormatter.parse()* method convert the string to PetType entity for controller to handle.

My question is that I have many entities needed to do this kind of formatting. After copying the code and creating more then 10 Formatters for different entity objects, I feel there must be better pattern to make the code look more concise. Can any one give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: Store them in a database and look them up by id? Have your entities implement some `interface` the described this functionality and then use one formatter for all implementing classes.

Comment: I do have functions like retrieving entities by ID. I still can't figure out how to write only one formatter for all implementing classes as you said. Could you please explain more about this?